# Symfony2 - custom css for select in forms

Tags: css, select, symfony, width

i have a little problem with the rendering of my forms. 
I would like my different select box have different size.

```
<div >
 {{ form_label(form.date_of_birth, 'date de naissance') }}
 {{ form_widget(form.date_of_birth )}}
</div>

<div >
 {{ form_label(form.Alimentation, 'Alimentation') }}
 {{ form_widget(form.Alimentation)}}
</div>
```

This two widgets renders select box. I want the two to have a different size, one large, one thin.. But, i can't directly set the style of the , and set the width of the div does nothing.
I also tried this:

> ->add('date_of_birth', 'date', array('required' => false, 'attr' => array('style' => 'width:330px' ),
>                                                                   'widget' => 'choice',
>                                                                   'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
>                                                                   'years' => range(1970,2012)))

This does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained in **Twig Template Form Function Reference** http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

```
{{  form_widget(form.name, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'yourClass' } })  }}
```

Now you have added a class attribute to your form field with yourClass as css class. So you can style your field using css.

Comment: Well, my css was overided by a link to http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css"> that i forgot to delete.. And in bootstrap, select is set to 220px.. Problem solved, thanks artworkad